# cbind the same data frame to a number of different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, csv, cbind

I have 200 separate data frames (1 col by 1500 rows). I need to `cbind` the same ID dataframe (2 cols by 1500 rows) to each of the 200 separate data frames.

```
ID_Data 

OB UIP
79  78
80  79
153 152
154 153 
155 154
156 155

 data_1
 0.000000
 4.260000
 5.700000
 6.574272
 5.790000
 9.360000
```

I need the data frame below: (At the end I need 200 dataframes that look like this - but each has different data in the data_1 column (i.e 200 data frames data_1:data_200) and all are saved as .csv to file)

```
OB UIP  data_1
79  78  0.000000
80  79  4.260000
153 152 5.700000
154 153 6.574272
155 154 5.790000
156 155 9.360000
```

I can hard code this using `cbind` and `fwrite` (below), but that is highly inefficient.

```
data1<-cbind(ID_Data,data_1)
fwrite(data1, "filepath")
```

I made a vector of dataframe names and attempted to loop over them and `cbind` the ID datset to them - but I couldn't get anything to work. I'm sure there is a simple solution here - I just can't come up with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read the datasets into a list instead of creating multiple objects i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(mget(paste0("data_", 1:200)), function(x) cbind(ID_Data, x))`

Comment: Amazing! this worked perfectly - you have saved me so much time. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Load the values of datasets into a `list` with `mget`, loop over the `list` with `lapply` and `cbind` with the ID_Data

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(paste0("data_", 1:200)), function(x) cbind(ID_Data, x))
```